# Accelerating convergence of a product by multiplying by zeta values: history?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, ho.history-overview, computational-number-theory, euler-product

Let $R(s_1,\dotsc,s_n) = \prod_p r(p^{-s_1},\dotsc,p^{-s_n})$, where
$r$ is a rational function on $n$ variables. Say we want to compute the value of $R(s_1,\dotsc,s_n)$ for some choice of $s_1,\dotsc,s_n$ for which the infinite product converges. As is well-known and simple to see, we can accelerate greatly the speed of convergence (and thus greatly shorten computation time for a desired level of accuracy) by first multiplying or dividing $R(s_1,\dotsc,s_n)$ by some well-chosen values of the $\zeta$ function.

When was this observation first made, at least for some particular $R$? I've heard of mentions of Gauss and/or Ramanujan, but it would be good to have an actual reference. A friend guesses that Rosser and Schoenfeld must have proceeded in this way to compute certain constants in the 1960s, but, again, I do not have a reference, and would need one.

Comment: An example from the 1960s is Bateman and Horn's paper on the Bateman-Horn conjecture: "A Heuristic Asymptotic Formula Concerning the Distribution of Prime Numbers" Math. Comp. 16 (1962), pp. 363-367. On p. 365 they rewrite an infinite product over $p$ by removing a factor equal to some $L(1,\chi)$.

Comment: I can say what they do, but they don't say what they are doing or why. I've tracked down an older reference - A. E. Western, "Note on the number of primes of the form n^2+ 1" - Cambridge Phil. Soc., Proc, 1922 (https://archive.org/stream/proceedingscambr21camb#page/108/mode/2up), where the idea (in a particular case) is credited to Littlewood - can someone find an older instance?

Comment: There are other references in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2712815/not-too-slow-computation-of-euler-products-singular-series , though not all may be immediately relevant.